# Is there an fix for FlatList that can pass a function?

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up a FlatList, and want it will show my component inside it.
I made a function "renderEpisodes" that include my component and I want to pass this function inside the FlatList that it will show me all my details that include in there.

This is my FlatList with all the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, FlatList, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import EpisodeDetail from './EpisodeDetail';
import { Spinner } from './Spinner';

class EpisodeList extends Component {

    state = { episodes: [] };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1/episodes')
        .then(Response => this.setState({ episodes: Response.data }));
    }

    renderEpisodes() {
       return this.state.episodes.map(episode =>
         <EpisodeDetail key={episode.name} episode={episode} />

         );
    }


    render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
             {this.renderEpisodes()}  
        />





    );
  }

}

export default EpisodeList;
```

I expect the output of the FlatList will show me all content of the function "renderEpisodes" because of its include all my component stuff that I want to show.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, FlatList, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import EpisodeDetail from './EpisodeDetail';
import { Spinner } from './Spinner';

class EpisodeList extends Component {

    state = { episodes: [] };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1/episodes')
        .then(Response => this.setState({ episodes: Response.data }));
    }

    renderEpisodes(episode) {
       return (
         <EpisodeDetail key={episode.name} episode={episode} />

         );
    }


    render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
             data={this.state.episodes}
             renderItem={({item}) => this.renderEpisodes(item)}
        />

    );
  }

}

export default EpisodeList;
```

Comment: It works very slowly and then the app collapses !
because it call the function all the time inside it and it put my json again and again untill it collapse..

Answer (score 1):

```
renderEpisodes({item,index}) {
   return <EpisodeDetail key={index} episode={item} />
}
```

......

```
<FlatList data={this.state.episodes} renderItem={this.renderEpisodes}/>
```

Comment: its work, but why i cant see the spinner when i scroll down the screen ?

Comment: scrollEnabled={true } add in flatList